# Multiple modals listening to the same keypress, how do I handle priority?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out the logic behind a problem, I'm hoping someone has any advice on how to solve this.

The app is built with React.

This is the flow of my applications:

- Use clicks on something
- A modal pops up with a form that needs to be filled
- Once the form is filled the user clicks a "Submit" button
- A confirmation modal pops up on top of the first modal

For accessibility and usability reasons I'd like both my modals to listen for the <kbd>ESC</kbd> keypress, so they can be easily cancelled from the keyboard. I've implemented this and it works, but it's not great.

I do this by calling an `useEffect` when the component is rendered:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e: KeyboardEvent) => {
      if (e.isComposing || e.keyCode === 27) {
        // close modal
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handler);
    };
  }, []);
```

The problem I'm facing is that if both modals are open and <kbd>ESC</kbd> is pressed, both modals will close.

How would you set priority for which modal gets closed first? I've thought about having a global modal object where I can check which modal is the latest added, but that seems needlessly complex.

Is there a simple solution I'm missing?

Here's a simple diagram explaining my problem.

[image]

Comment: Can't you just check for the second modal existence in the handler of the first modal? If it's there, don't close the first modal on esc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the handler of the first Modal check for the existance of the second Modal. If it's there, don't close the first one :)